# Computing an infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} e(\frac{n}{n + 1})^n * \sqrt\frac{n}{n + 1}$

Tags: calculus, contest-math, infinite-product

[image]

The answer to the question is $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}e$, although I do not know how to come to this solution. This is a problem from a math contest from the year 2016.

Comment: The $N$th partial product is $$\prod_{n=1}^N\left(en^{n+1/2}(n+1)^{-(n+1)+1/2}\right)=e^N\prod_{n=1}^Nn^{n+1/2}\prod_{n=2}^{N+1}n^{-n+1/2}=e^NN!(N+1)^{-N-1/2}$$ and Stirling formula readily yields the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg [e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}  \,\Bigg ]=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^N \Bigg [e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}  \,\Bigg ]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}e^N\left[\left(\frac 12\right)^1\left(\frac 23\right)^2\left(\frac 34\right)^3\cdots \left(\frac N{N+1}\right)^N\right]
\sqrt{\frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34\cdots\frac{N}{N+1}}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}e^N\left[\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots N}{(N+1)^N}{\cdot \frac{N+1}{N+1}}\right]\sqrt\frac1{N+1}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}e^N\frac{{(N+1)!}}{(N+1)^{N+\frac{3}{2}}}\\
\end{align*}
Hope you can take it from here using Stirling formula.

Comment: Hey I know this is old but how can I use Stirling's formula on this? I tried researching it.

Comment: @Ekesh $\displaystyle \left ( N+1 \right )!\sim \sqrt{2\pi(N+1)}\left(\frac{N+1}e\right)^{N+1}$, take some limit and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm of such product is given by
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{n+\tfrac{1}{2}-x}{x}\,dx $$
that is:
$$ -\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t}{n+\tfrac{1}{2}+t}\,dt = -\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{u^2}{(2n+1)^2-u^2}\,du$$
or, by considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the cosine function,
$$ -\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}+\frac{\pi u}{4}\tan\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)\right)\,du $$
that is:
$$ -\lim_{t\to 1^-}\left(t-\text{arctanh}(t)-\tfrac{t}{2}\log\cos\tfrac{\pi t}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\right){=}\tfrac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-1. $$
Exponentiating back, we get that the value of the infinite product is $\color{red}{\large\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}}$ without exploiting Stirling's approximation.